# What are the differences between matrices, tenosrs and dyads?

Tags: matrices, tensors

What are the major differences between matrices, tensors and dyads?
Where and when are each of these used?
Why do we need to define these concepts separately?

Comment: A dyad is a certain kind of tensor. A matrix is an array of coefficients that represent components of a certain kind of tensors in a given basis. Matrices, dyads and tensors are linked, but they are not exactly the same.